# iOS dictation duplicated

Tags: ios, voice-dictation

My wife and I both run into a problem with some regularity on our iOS phones where the dictation (via the microphone button off stock iOS keyboard) will get duplicated. Often we dictate 10-25 words and suddenly it has inserted them all twice, as if we repeated what we had said a second time. Really annoying and have seen this for at least a year. We have seen it with both emails and texts. Appreciate any suggestions or a link to a public Radar ticket we can up-vote.

iOS version 12.4.1 currently, but has happened on earlier versions.

(There was a laughable suggestion on Apple support community that sounded like a Windows support call from 2002: "reboot phone, then reinstall iOS, and see if that fixes it.")

Comment: This has happened a few times to me lately, but only in non-Apple apps like Gmail. I frequently dictate texts on the move, and I don't recall this ever happening.

Comment: Is this with the stock iOS keyboard, 3rd party keyboard, or Siri?  Also, please update your question to include the iOS version.

Comment: @fsb Updated with both, iOS 12.4.1 and mic button off stock keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, I just figured it out!  I am using iPhone X 13.1.3 however, I think this would work on all iPhones and ios versions.
~ Go to settings
~Scroll down to Accessibility
~Scroll down to Voice Control and change it to OFF

I also had a microphone showing on my lock screen in the top left hand corner and this went away, as well as the duplicates when talking to text.  I tested it by switching it on and off to see if it fixed the problem and it did. Woohoo!  It was quite annoying.  I hope this helps :)

Comment: Glad that did it for you. But voice control is already off for me. Still happening in iOS 13.1.3. Long standing bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've been plagued with the same annoying recurring problem. Very time-consuming to have to Cursor over and delete the duplicated text. I checked my accessibility and it was already set to voice control off. I dug a bit further and there is a second section, customize commands > that has multiple options. At the bottom of the list is “accessibility “. When you tap that, more options are listed.  One of them says “Turn off voice control” and the button is either on or off. Mine says off. When I tap “off” it doesn't turn it back on but takes me to yet another screen of options. “Enabled” and ”Confirmation required”. I think this has more to do with commanding my phone by voice than by dictating text to Siri.

The only item I don't get is how to eliminate Siri
Dictation duplication in practice so we don't need these workarounds and half measures.